# Install Oracle-database-18c-xe on ubuntu error ORA-07445

Tags: oracle

Today I try to install oracle-18c-xe on ubuntu but I did play with error ORA-07445. 
I did by follow guide:
https://chronicler.tech/mint-oracle-18c-xe/
https://www.evaristorivieccio.es/2018/11/xe-oracle-18c-en-ubuntu-oracle-database.html

I stuck at command: 
/etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c configure

with error:
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel

Here detail from trace log:

```
Exception [type: SIGSEGV, SI_KERNEL(general_protection)] [ADDR:0x0] [PC:0x7F40B3F4EF42, adjtime()+3346] [flags: 0x0, count: 1]
Errors in file /opt/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace/XE_ora_4266.trc  (incident=7):
ORA-07445: exception encountered: core dump [adjtime()+3346] [SIGSEGV] [ADDR:0x0] [PC:0x7F40B3F4EF42] [SI_KERNEL(general_protection)] []
Incident details in: /opt/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/incident/incdir_7/XE_ora_4266_i7.trc
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.

[ default][ default]u_set_comp_error: comptype '103' : error '29'
[   CLWAL][   CLWAL]clsw_Initialize: Error [32] from procr_init_ext
[   CLWAL][   CLWAL]clsw_Initialize: Error [PROCL-32: Oracle High Availability Services on the local node is not running Messaging error [gipcretConnectionRefused] [29]] from procr_init_ext
2020-06-16 12:42:26.066 : [    GPNP][    GPNP] clsgpnpkww_initclswcx: [at clsgpnpkww.c:353] Result: (56) CLSGPNP_OCR_INIT. (:GPNP01201:)Failed to init CLSW-OLR context. CLSW Error (3): CLSW-3: Error in the cluster registry (OCR) layer. [32] [PROCL-32: Oracle High Availability Services on the local node is not running Messaging error [gipcretConnectionRefused] [29]]
2020-06-16 12:42:26.066 : [    GPNP][    GPNP] clsgpnpwu_walletfopen: [at clsgpnpwu.c:382] Result: (66) CLSGPNP_WALLET_NONE. (:GPNP01603:)Wallet file not found: '/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/gpnp/epay/wallets/prdr/cwallet.sso'
2020-06-16 12:42:26.066 : [    GPNP][    GPNP] clsgpnpwu_walletfopen: [at clsgpnpwu.c:500] Result: (66) CLSGPNP_WALLET_NONE. (:GPNP01610:)Cannot open wallet: '/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/gpnp/epay/wallets/prdr/cwallet.sso'
2020-06-16 12:42:26.066 : [    GPNP][    GPNP] clsgpnp_getCK: [at clsgpnp0.c:2871] (:GPNP00233:)Fatal error: failed to get local gpnp security keys (wallet). Gpnp profiles cannot be verified. ***LOCAL GPNP SETUP INVALID***.>
2020-06-16 12:42:26.066 : [    GPNP][    GPNP] clsgpnp_InitIdSetCtxCK: [at clsgpnp0.c:5611] Result: (59) CLSGPNP_OCR_NOSRV. (:GPNP00267:)Cannot get stored certkey for id=1
2020-06-16 12:42:26.066 : [    GPNP][    GPNP] clsgpnp_Init: [at clsgpnp0.c:1055] Result: (59) CLSGPNP_OCR_NOSRV. (:GPNP00211:)Error getting certkeys. 
2020-06-16 12:42:26.066 : [    GPNP][    GPNP] clsgpnp_Init init failed. Error: CLSGPNP_ERR (1) .
2020-06-16 12:42:26.066 : [ CLSINET][ CLSINET] Failed to initialize clsgpnp context grv 1
```

Please help me! Thank you so much!

Comment: It says there's a trace file: `/opt/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace/XE_ora_4266.trc`. Have you looked in that?

Comment: @APC Yes, The detail from trace log I posted above.

Comment: Note that no version of Oracle is supported on Ubuntu, regardless of what some blog has described. The error ORA-03113 indicates that your connection was killed unexpectedly, as from a core dump. From the trace you posted, it appears that this may be a permissions issue with a directory and/or that some other part of your installation has failed. As long as you use a configuration like this you can expect more random errors like this to pop up. If you expect help with something like this, please use a supported configuration which people would actually have widespread experience using.

Comment: @pmdba Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there are several 'branches' of the Linux family tree, and oracle is designed for a completely different branch than where Ubuntu lives.  You have found one of the many hacks to get oracle to install on Ubuntu, but that's exactly what it is -- a hack.
As @pmda said, you will just continue to run into issues.

The solution is to create a vm on your ubuntu, then install Oracle Linux on that vm, and create your database there.  See [here](https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/category/personal-test-systems/).  My personal laptop is running Ubuntu, and the vm approach is exactly what I've done.

Comment: Thank you so much!